# HTTP POST 400 error

Tags: http-status-codes

I see following in the access log of Apache 2.2.22

POST TEST HTTP/1.1 400 - - 443

Seems a bad request returned by the server to the client request. Shouldn't the "TEST" be "/TEST"?  Is there any way that I can simulate similar POST 400 error using curl or telnet?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly you see this in your Apache log. You don´t know the reason for it but wants to recreate it?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. A client is sending the request causing the 400 error. It seems the POST method is wrong isn't it? I want to recreate it to understand/confirm that the request is bad somehow.

Comment: When I was creating http-requests for an api I wrote some time ago I had hard times getting the eol-character right before I foud the end of line-problem. I don´t remember if the protocol specification states eol = lf/cr or cr/lf or lf or cr but sending the wrong line ending will make the whole request invalid, at least in apache. Maby examin the exact hex sequence of the request will give you the answare. Good luck.